# fittext and wordpress the content

Tags: php, wordpress

we're in completing our new page in WP but we have some problems with the_content string that doesn't accept the id of fittext then the text doesn't auto fit!

We have applied the fit text to other strings and these are ok.

We have also installed the plugin that delete the WPAUTOP and we've created the string in  single.php:

```
<p id="fittext2">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

the_content();
endwhile;
?>
</p>
```

I can visualize perfectly the content, with format, but with no effects of fit text!

this is the link with the problem, on every image the single.php appear in one lightbox:
http://www.cemab.com/cms

Comment: What's the problem to be precise?

Answer (score 1):

when you type content in the admin panel the text auro adjust and add

tags  try this plugin wich k can remove auto formatting http://wordpress.org/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/